# Notepad++ regex Insert string at beginning of line between two values

Tags: regex

How can I insert at the start of a line a string dependent on two other string values that define beginning and end locations?

So for example, I have

`First`

`x`

`y`

`z`

`Second`

`a`

`b`

`c`

`Third`

`d`

`e`

`f`

The result I would like to achieve is;

`First`

`Q1 x`

`Q1 y`

`Q1 z`

`Second`

`Q2 a`

`Q2 b`

`Q2 c`

`Third`

`Q3 d`

`Q3 e`

`Q3 f`

For the final section there is no string to define the end but just the end of the document.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task cannot be done using pure regex(this can be proven mathematically), you would have to use something like the Notepad++ Python plugin.
This post has an example: https://superuser.com/questions/376288/how-do-i-add-input-to-my-macro-to-replace-text-in-notepad . For your task you just need to change the input parameter to the latest read cardinal number